# Can i still get appstore reviews by python?

Tags: python, app-store, review

as title i need to get reviews and rates , dates from appstore.
i got github.com/don9z/appstore from GitHub

here is the code:

```
import feedparser
from datetime import datetime
import calendar

app_contries = {
'China':'cn',
'United States':'us'}

app_sortby = {
'Most Recent':'mostRecent',
'Most Helpful':'mostHelpful',
# 'Most Favorable':'mostFavorable',
# 'Most Critical':'mostCritical'}

def mk_appfeed(app_id, country_code, sortby=app_sortby['Most Recent']):
return 'https://itunes.apple.com/%s/rss/customerreviews/id=%s/sortBy=%s/xml' %\
    (country_code,app_id, sortby)

def parse_feed(url):
review_map = {}
feed = feedparser.parse(url)
review_map.setdefault('title', feed.feed['title'])
review_map.setdefault('updated',
                      calendar.timegm(feed.feed['updated_parsed']))

if not feed.entries:
    print 'Get nothing from ' + url
    return None
review_map.setdefault('apptitle', feed.entries[0]['title'])
review_map.setdefault('applink', feed.entries[0]['id'])

reviews = []
for entry in feed.entries[1:]:
    reviews.append({'title': entry['title'],
                    'content': entry['content'][0]['value'],
                    'author': entry['author'],
                    'rating': entry['im_rating'],
                    'updated': calendar.timegm(entry['updated_parsed'])
                })
review_map.setdefault('reviews', reviews)
return review_map

def print_reviews(review_map):
if not review_map:
    print 'Input None'
    return

print 'Title:    %s' % review_map['title']
print 'Updated:  %s' % datetime.fromtimestamp(review_map['updated'])
print 'App Name: %s' % review_map['apptitle']
print 'Link:     %s' % review_map['applink']

index = 0
for entry in review_map['reviews']:
    index+=1
    print '*** %d ***' % index
    print 'Title:    %s' % entry['title']
    print 'Content:  %s' % entry['content']
    print 'Author:   %s' % entry['author']
    print 'Rating:   %s' % entry['rating']
    print 'Updated   %s' % datetime.fromtimestamp(entry['updated'])

def get_app_reviews(app_id, country_name, sortby='Most Recent'):
print_reviews(parse_feed(mk_appfeed(app_id, app_contries[country_name],
                                    app_sortby[sortby])))
```

and i just use call.py

```
import review
review.get_app_reviews('506627515', 'United States')
```

but the command return

```
Title:    iTunes Store: Customer Reviews
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "call.py", line 3, in <module>
review.get_app_reviews('506627515', 'United States')
File "/Users/Eric/Desktop/appstore-master/review.py", line 71, in get_app_reviews
app_sortby[sortby])))
File "/Users/Eric/Desktop/appstore-master/review.py", line 54, in print_reviews
print 'Updated:  %s' % datetime.fromtimestamp(review_map['updated'])
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'fromtimestamp'
```

it seems got problem with datetime 
i just try to find out where is the problem 
by the way me python is 2.7.0 and i think is the version problem？

needs help

Comment: You should post your entire code -- the command from the error message is not in your question.

Comment: it's done . just find out where the problem is :)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in `datetime`, the `fromtimestamp` command is in the `date` module, cf [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromtimestamp). Thus, change your code to

```
import datetime
print 'Updated:  %s' % datetime.date.fromtimestamp(review_map['updated'])
```

Note that the item in `review_map` is created by `calendar.timegm()`, which returns a Unix timestamp, cf [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.timegm).

Just for illustrative purposes, the complete procedure is thus something like

```
datetime.date.fromtimestamp(calendar.timegm(time.gmtime()))
```

> returns datetime.date(2017, 7, 12)

If your `entry` object returns the correct format, this should work.